# Can we reduce High water mark by using Gather stats in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am very new to oracle and I have below query.

I have one table which has almost 6 L records.
In daily batch i need to delete almost 5.7 L record and insert it again in from another table. Note that i can not use truncate table because 30000 records are constant one which I should not delete.
Issue here is if I delete daily 5.67 L record, it may cause for High WaterMark issue.

So my query is can Gather Stats helps to reduce HWM?
I can do Oracle Gather Stats Daily.

Comment: May you please post both the table structure and sample data and your expected result? There might be a simple solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: Did you consider partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SHRINK command to recover the space and reset the high water mark:

```
alter table your_table shrink space;
```

However, you should only do this if you need to. In your case it seems likely you need only do this if you are inserting your 567,000 records using the `/* APPEND */` hint; this hint tells the optimiser to insert records above the HWM, which in your scenario would cause the table to grow, with vast amounts of empty space. Shrinking would definitely be useful here.

If you're just inserting records without the hint then they will mainly reuse the empty space vacated by the prior deletion, so you don't need to concern yourself with the HWM.

---

Incidentally, deleting and re-inserting 5.67L records every day sounds rather poor practice. There are probably better solutions (such as MERGE), depending on the underlying business rules you're trying to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

If you reinsert the same amount of data, the table should be roughly the same size. Therefore, I would not worry about the high water mark too much.

Having said that, it is good practice to gather statistics if the data has changed substantially, so I would recommend that.